# Insert the directive in the column of the table AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a table component that takes the names of the columns and rows with the data that I want to display in the table. But not always data is a simple text. Sometimes I want to add my own directive.

For example, there is a controller with its own template, in which I want to add my own table component. In the controller, I set the data I want to transfer to the table:

```
ctrl.tableData = [
  { name: 'Alex', age: '34', mobile: '<my-directive ng-model="ctrl.mobile">' }
];
```

Then in the template I send this data to the table:

```
<my-table-component data="ctrl.tableData"></my-table-component>
```

Well, in the component `my-table-component` a table is drawn:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in ctrl.data">
    <td ng-repeat="column in ctrl.columns">{{ row[column] }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With this implementation of the table, I can not insert the directive, since it will be inserted simply by the text. For this, I created an additional directive that compiles directives. Let its name be `my-table-directive`. It does the following:

```
function link (scope, element, attrs) {
  const columnElem = angular.element(element);

  let columnChild = attrs.columnValue;

  if (attrs.columnValue.startsWith('<')) {
    columnChild = $compile(columnChild)(scope);
  }

  columnElem.append(columnChild);
}
```

And my table template has slightly changed:

```
<td ng-repeat="column in ctrl.columns">
    column-value={{row[column]}}
    my-table-directive></td>
```

Everything seems to be okay. But the problem is that the directive is not compiled at all with the scope that is expected :)
Naturally, I want to change the `mobile` property in my topmost sketch, where I set `ctrl.tableData`. And with the current implementation of the `ng-model`, `my-directive` directive will write the data into the `mobile` property of my `<td>` scope in the table.

Maybe my decision is not quite right? Could you somehow organize the insertion of directives in the component-table in a different way? The task seems popular, but nothing happened to google it. Help me, please :)

Comment: Several scopes will be created along the way to your deeply nested `my-directive` element. By the time `ng-model` tries to bind to `ctrl.mobile` as you've written, that scope isn't the same one as the outermost one. To prove my point, here's a minimal demo that deliberately reaches up several scopes: http://plnkr.co/edit/u1FzCvsOy1YNnNFqSk5Z?p=preview The fact you want to modify a property from a deeply nested component, presumably via two-way binding is a code smell. Prefer using events or a service instead.